# Why is my calculator program not working - Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

I'm writing a program for a calculator but i'm experiencing a small problem.
Whenever I press one of the buttons, it increases numbers by 9 every time, even though it should be i (from the for loop).
Please can someone tell me why its always 9 please?

Code -

```
import tkinter

plus = True

numbers = 0

def main():

    def numButton(i):
        global numbers
        if plus == False:
            numbers-=i
        else:
            numbers+=i
    def quitHandler():
        root.destroy()
    def entryHandler():
        global numbers
        numbers+=int(text.get())
        text.set("")
    def printHandler():
        text2.set(numbers)
    def restartHandler():
        global numbers
        root.destroy()
        plus = True
        numbers = 0
        main()
    def plusHandler():
        global plus
        plus = True
    def minusHandler():
        global plus
        plus = False

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    frame = tkinter.Frame(root).pack(side=tkinter.TOP)

    text = tkinter.IntVar()
    text2 = tkinter.IntVar()
    text.set("")
    text2.set("")

    tkinter.Entry(frame,bd =8,textvariable=text).pack()

    tkinter.Button(frame,padx=8,pady=8,bd=8,text="Enter",command=entryHandler).pack()
    tkinter.Button(frame,padx=8,pady=8,bd=8,text="Quit",command=quitHandler).pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
    tkinter.Button(frame,padx=8,pady=8,bd=8,text="Restart",command=restartHandler).pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
    tkinter.Button(frame,padx=8,pady=8,bd=8,text="Print",command=printHandler).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

    tkinter.Entry(frame,bd =8,textvariable=text2).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

    _padx = 16
    _pady = 16
    _bd = 8

    for i in range (1,10):
        tkinter.Button(frame, padx = _padx, pady = _pady, bd = _bd, text = str(i), command = lambda: numButton(i)).pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)

    tkinter.Button(frame,padx=8,pady=8,bd=8,text="+",command=plusHandler).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
    tkinter.Button(frame,padx=8,pady=8,bd=8,text="-",command=minusHandler).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

main()
```

Could someone also tell me how to put all of it inside the code thing on this site, I cant figure it out and the ways the site's help shows me isn't working ( or admin fix please ).

---

OK thanks guys, someone's emailed me the solution:

```
    tkinter.Button(frame, padx = _padx, pady = _pady, bd = _bd, text = str(i), command = lambda i=i: numButton(i)).pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)
```

Had to add the i=i after the lamda.
Can someone explain to me what the i=i thing does please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
command = lambda: numButton(i)
```

This doesn't look up the value of `i` at the time of the lambda's creation and insert it into the function. When the lambda is called, *then* it looks up `i`. `i` is always `9` by that time.

There are several ways to get around the problem, all focused on ensuring that `i` is looked up at `command`'s creation time instead of execution time. The one I'd use is `functools.partial`, a tool designed to associate a function with arguments:

```
from functools import partial
...
command=partial(numButton, i)
```

You can also use a default argument, which is kind of kludgy:

```
command=lambda i=i: numButton(i)
```

Or write a factory function:

```
def closure_maker(i):
    def closure():
        numButton(i)
    return closure
...
command=closure_maker(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The lambda functions used for the commands reference the variable `i`:

```
for i in range (1,10):
    tkinter.Button(frame, padx = _padx, pady = _pady, bd = _bd, text = str(i),
            command = lambda: numButton(i)).pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)
```

When the command is executed and the lambda function runs, it selects button number `i`. But at that time, when the lambda function is executed, `i` contains the value `9` (That's the value `i` ends up with after the `for` loop that created the buttons was complete.

To solve this issue, make sure the lambda functions don't all share the same global variable. One way would be to use a function which creates a new local scope:

```
def numCommand(x):
    return (lambda: numButton(x))

for i in range (1,10):
    tkinter.Button(frame, padx = _padx, pady = _pady, bd = _bd, text = str(i),
            command = numCommand(i)).pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)
```

Here each lambda function refers to its own `x` variable from its `numCommand()` call.